# MySQL Character Issue When Using UPDATE Statement with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make user create a profile for them. To do this I gave them some choices with divs. Every div has their own id. When options are selected and clicked submit selected divs' id's are placed into hidden input and then sent to profil_olustur.php as POST variables. In that page i use this script:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    // DB connection is here 

$baglan = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
include_once "fonksiyonlar/girdikontrol.php";


if (isset($_POST['profil_fakulte']) && !empty($_POST['profil_fakulte']) && isset($_POST['profil_bolum']) && !empty($_POST['profil_bolum'])) {

    $profil_fakulte_temiz = kontrol($_POST['profil_fakulte']); //variable from hidden input 
    $profil_bolum_temiz = kontrol($_POST['profil_bolum']); // variable from hidden input
    $ka = $_SESSION['kullaniciadi']; //username

    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'  ");
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_turkish_ci' ");

    $bilgi_ekle = mysql_query("UPDATE kayitli SET profiloldumu='1',fakulte='$profil_fakulte_temiz' , bolum='$profil_bolum_temiz' WHERE kullaniciadi = '$ka' " ); //Updating two columns(fakulte and bolum) in $username's row 

    $_SESSION['kayit_bilgi'] = 'Profilin oluşturuldu. Tekrar giriş yap'; // A message to inform user whether is profile created or not.
    $_SESSION['girildi'] = 0; // Make user to logout
    Header("Location: index.php"); // And goes index.php
} else {
    Header("Location: profilolustur.php"); // if variables are not sent goes back the same page
}
```

When I update user's that two column(fakulte and bolum) I can't use Turkish characters. It writes

```
U&ccedil;ak ve Uzay Bilimleri Fak&uuml;ltesi
```

instead of

```
Uçak ve Uzay Bilimleri Fakültesi
```

or

```
U&cce
```

instead of

```
UCK
```

which I am very surprised because the second one doesn't involve even Turkish character. Besides I can edit `fakulte` and `bolum` columns and I can use Turkish characters but I can't do that with PHP. What is the problem ?

Eventhough i applied these procedures they didn't work.

1. Deleted the whole database and created again and choosed utf8_general_ci for
2. I  added these piece of code just before using UPDATE query or right after connecting to database 
       mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'  ");
       mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
       mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_turkish_ci' ");
3. I added 
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
   to my php file and HTML file

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and are likely to be removed in the next major release. Instead, switch to either `MySQLi` or `PDO`, both are easy to get a grasp of with great examples in the docs.

Comment: Just before your query, place `$db->set_charset("utf8");` am not 100% sure if this will work for `mysql_` but it does work for `mysqli_` which you really need to switch to.

Comment: @TerryHarvey Thanks for your heads up. I'm newbiee to MySQL and PHP. At first I started with mysql and go on like that. As I keep going learning and looking for security suggestions I always saw that mysql_ shouldn't be used and mysqli_ should be used instead. But when I try to replace all mysql_ with mysqli_ I got an error. Because of I need to publish my site at these days I cant change. But as soon as i publish my site i will change it. Thanks.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I got this error  `Call to a member function set_charset() on a non-object`

Comment: I'm under the impression you may have tried converting `mysql_` to `mysqli_`, yes? If so, how did you do it? Those 2 functions don't work exactly the same.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just added 'i' . Then i learned from PHP manual that it takes different parameters than mysql_ .But didn't understand which parameters should i use

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr-TR.utf8');
```

Comment: I'm newbie to MySQL and PHP. Where should I put this?

Comment: I put it right after `mysql_select_db($db);`. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the tables and the columns that you're storing the data in use the utf8_unicode_ci collation.